# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-image"

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have created a gui using Page GUI builder on my linux. It has a frame and a canvas. I am trying to play a video on one of the frame. 
Now when i run the code i gets _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-image" error. I tried similar questions and their solutions but none of them worked. 
I am using Python3. For building the GUI tkinter is used.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 4.22
#  in conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Oct 25, 2019 12:16:56 PM IST  platform: Linux

import sys

try:
    import Tkinter as tk, threading
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk, threading

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import video_gui_support
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = Toplevel1 (root)
    video_gui_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Toplevel1 (w)
    video_gui_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Toplevel1():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None


class Toplevel1:

    def stream(self, label):

        video_name = "intro.mp4" #This is your video file path
        video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)

        for image in video.iter_data():
            frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
            label.configure(image=frame_image)
            label.image = frame_image

    def __init__(self, top=None):
        print("Started")
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        top.geometry("1920x1012+0+0")
        top.title("New Toplevel")

        self.Frame1 = tk.Frame(top)
        self.Frame1.place(relx=0.531, rely=0.01, relheight=0.983, relwidth=0.466)

        self.Frame1.configure(relief='groove')
        self.Frame1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.Frame1.configure(relief="groove")
        self.Frame1.configure(width=895)

        # Code to run video file
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream, args=(self.Frame1,))
        thread.daemon = 1
        thread.start()


        self.Canvas1 = tk.Canvas(top)
        self.Canvas1.place(relx=0.005, rely=0.01, relheight=0.982
            , relwidth=0.521)
        self.Canvas1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.Canvas1.configure(relief="ridge")
        self.Canvas1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Canvas1.configure(width=1001)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Error got -

```
Started
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "video_gui.py", line 80, in stream
 label.configure(image=frame_image)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-image"
```

Comment: IMO it's most likely due to the fact that tkinter doesn't support multithreading in the sense that only one thread, usually the main one, can use it. The non-GUI threads will often store their results in a `Queue`, which the GUI thread can poll and change the user-interface accordingly. The polling is often done by using the universal [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method. There are numerous example of using it in answer here.

Comment: You are passing a `Frame` in `threading.Thread(target=self.stream, args=(self.Frame1,))`. A frame cannot take an image as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an instance of a `Frame` to `stream`. This is the parameter `label`. You then try to configure the image of this frame, but a frame does not have a `image` attribute.

If you want to display an image, you will need to create an instance of `Label` or some other widget that supports images.